# f,g differentiable, f(x)g'(x) - f'(x)g(x) = 0, f(a) = 0, g(a)$\neq$0 then $\exists \epsilon$ such that f(x)=0 $\forall x \in (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, derivatives

this is my attemp

if f(x)g'(x) - f'(x)g(x) = 0 then (f/g)'(a) = 0

if g is constant then f(x)g(x) - f'(x)g(x) = 0 then f'(x) = 0, f(x) is constant, but f(a) = 0 then f(x) = 0

if g(x) is non constant i have tried it by absurd reduction.

Supose $\forall \epsilon$ > 0 $\exists$ x such that f(x) $\neq$ 0

i think that there is a way to come to $\exists x$ such that f(x)g'(x) -f'(x)g(x) $\neq 0$

but i dont know how to continue:c

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please consider using MathJax to typeset mathematical expressions in your posts. Also, how's this related to "General Topology"?

Comment: By continuity of $g$, $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $\forall x\in(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon), g(x)\ne 0$. Actually $$\exists \epsilon>0, \forall x, \left(0<|x-a|<\epsilon \implies |g(x)-g(a)|<|g(a)|\right)$$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g(a)\neq 0$ then by continuity $g(x)\neq 0$ over some $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$. Then first of all dividing by $g(x)$ is well defined, and moreover

$$\bigg(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\bigg)'=\frac{f(x)g'(x)-f'(x)g(x)}{g(x)^2}$$

which is equal to $0$ by our assumption. And so $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=C$ for some constant $C$, independent of $x$. Or equivalently $f(x)=Cg(x)$. But $f(a)=0$, and therefore $C=0$ is the only possible choice since $g(a)\neq 0$. Meaning $f(x)=0$ over entire $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$.